# Tournament Tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I need to build a tournament tree, but I'm getting confused how to initialize the tree. I have an array of team names. The thing that I don't understand is how initialize the array. If for example I have 6 teams (a,b,c,d,e,f) how I build the tree for end up with the follow three.

[image]

I know that this three have internal and external node. We have *n - 1* internal nodes, and *n* external nodes. Internal nodes store the winner of each match, and external store all the teams. The tree needs to be balanced. Ok until now its clear but, how I implement this? All internal nodes needs be a match and the outside nodes needs to be a team? And how I can build a balance three for make the tournament?

I try to build a stack, but its wrong because *e and f* match, the next one *d* match with the winner of *e and f*, but the next one is c and he match with the of ( d  match ( e match f) ).

As you can see I am a bit confused about this and I think is the way I'm looking the problem. I had tray to look on internet for see examples or some code for understanding, but I can't find anything, just some lecture how to order this data structure but nothing about initialize the three.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

Let's say yo have and array `[a,b,c]`, you should take the first 2 elements and make a match, remove them from the array, and add the match to the end of the array. You keep doing this until the array holds only one element.

`[a, b, c]`

`[c, match(a, b)]`

`[match(c, match(a,b))]`

Answer (score 0):

Always consider array in pair of element. 
Firstly, find height of tree required: `logn(base2)` -> rounding off to next integer, say height is `m`.
Number of leaf element: `2^m`.

Fill in leaf nodes starting from left till length of array and fill null for rest of nodes.

In your example:

```
log6 = 2.something -> 3

2^3 -> 8
```

Fill `a,b,c,d,e,f` in first 6 position and let 7th and 8th position be null.

Hope it helps.